# Python letter translation Cyrillic

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm creating script for beginners of learning Russian alphabet.
So I created script which first:

```
print "Give me letter: "
letter = raw_input()
```

ok then i made:

```
if letter == "a":
    print "Аа"
elif letter == "b":
    print "Бб"
elif letter == "be":
```

etc. That works good if I have insert 1 letter. For example "a".
But what if I want to insert "dog". (d - o - g). How to make it?

I'm just beginner and that's my first app in python actually.

edit. I also have :

```
letter = letter.lower()
```

(if that's important for someone)

Comment: `map(translate, word)`

Comment: I would be using a dictionary for the mappings

Answer (score 0):

What should happen if user have entered a word instead of a letter?

If you want to translate letter by letter, do the following:

```
word = raw_input()

for letter in word:
    translate(letter)  # translate is a function that translates single letter
```

Answer (score -1):

It may be easier to use the transilterate package (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/transliterate)

```
from transliterate import translit
x = input("Choose character(s)")
print translit(x, "ru")
```

Otherwise you could create a dicitonary of symbol translations to avoid a ton of if/else statements.  toCryllicWord will produce an array of upper and lower as it seems you are looking to accomplish, though I believe you will have to add exception handling for potential missing characters.

```
symbols = (u"abvgdeezijklmnoprstufh'y'eABVGDEEZIJKLMNOPRSTUFH'Y'E",
       u"абвгдеёзийклмнопрстуфхъыьэАБВГДЕЁЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЪЫЬЭ")

d = {a: b for a, b in zip(*symbols)}
def toCryllicWord(input):
    return ["".join([d[i.upper()] for i in input]),"".join([d[i.lower()] for i in input])]

print toCryllicWord('dog')[0]
```